# Лишние символы при взаимодействии C# клиента и C++ сервера по именованному каналу

Tags: c#, c++, pipes

Нужно соединить C# и C++ приложения именованным каналом. Сервер в отдельном потоке читает приходящие сообщения от клиента. Вместо ожидаемого приходят еще лишние символы. Фрагменты кода брал с MSDN.

Код С++ состоит только из:

- `CreateNamedPipe`
- `ConnectNamedPipe`
- `CreateThread`
- `ReadFile` (синхронный ввод в `char` массив).

Больше там ничего нет.

Код C# состоит только из:

- `NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(...)`
- `pipeClient.Connect()`
- `StreamString streamString = new StreamString(pipeClient)`
- `streamString.WriteString("Start")`

Вместо `Start` файл читается 2 раза и приходят символы `tart`, потом `Start`.

Comment: Что такое StreamString?..

Comment: Пишите массив байт - читайте массив байт.

Comment: Укажите ссылку на МСДН, пожалуйста

Comment: В .NET строки юникодные - один символ 2 байта. `char` в C++ - один байт. Может, в этом проблема?